# Help making conditionals in a macro

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, conditionals

I have this bit of code that list the author in bold and each their affiliations in italics everytime `\AddAuthor` is called and send all authors to TOC.

```
\newcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{} %container

\newcommand{\ListAuthor}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{##1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\quad#1\par}

    \renewcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{
        \textbf{##1} \\
        \textit{##2} \\
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to have the authors in TOC formatted nicely, separated by commas except the last one. This code, as you can see, only sends the authors separated by a space. I suppose one could make it by employing a counter and make conditionals, but so far I did no luck.

Here's the MWE that I did so far.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\newcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{} %container

\newcommand{\ListAuthor}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{##1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\quad#1\par}

    \renewcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{
        \textbf{##1} \\
        \textit{##2} \\
    }
    \vspace{-5ex}
    #1
    \vspace{5ex} 
}     


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{The Awesome Chapter}
\ListAuthor{
    \AddAuthor{First Author}{Goodest Boy}
    \AddAuthor{Second Author}{Not the Best One}
}

\chapter{The Awesome Chapter, part 2}
\ListAuthor{
    \AddAuthor{First Author}{Another Good Boy}
    \AddAuthor{Second Author}{The Best of Its Kind}
    \AddAuthor{Third Author}{The Baddie}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are authors listed in the Table of Contents? Generally, the TOC contains a list of sections, subsections, etc.

Comment: @Mico I'm working on a small anthology, and the authors differ each chapter, and some have different numbers of authors. The sections are omitted from TOC.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining your use case.

Comment: Please edit your posting to provide a compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that shows how you employ `\AddAuthor` and `\ListAuthor`.

Comment: Almost forgot. Edited! @Mico thanks.

Comment: After you asked this the first time, you got me thinking about using `\bibatex` to achieve this. As you deleted that one, I couldn't put this suggestion in a comment. Hence I put it in here now. Do you still wish to have the *affiliations*  listed somewhere too?

Comment: @alchemist For that one, I did messed up my request, as that one was written half tired so it came up as an incoherent mess. Actually, for the previous question, this is what I meant to achieve.

Comment: Usually, when citing an author of a chapter in a book, you create a bibliographical entry as `@inbook` and cite that in text. You're actually doing the same: creating `@inbook` references with your macro. If you add a *category* to your references and use `titletoc` and `titlesec` to define the chapters you might achieve want you want to as well,

Comment: That's actually an interesting idea. Thank you! I'll keep it in mind for future experiments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you do not want the last author separated by comma. How should it be separated instead??? Here is a solution, with comma between all authors:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\newcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{%
  \textbf{#1} \\
  \textit{#2} \\
}

\newcommand{\ListAuthor}[1]{% <-- to avoid potentially unwanted spaces
  \begingroup
    \def\AddAuthor{\string\AddAuthor}% local redefinition to write \AddAuthor commands to the toc
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begin{l@listauthors}#1\end{l@listauthors}}% write l@listauthor environment with all the \AddAuthor commands to the toc
  \endgroup
  \vspace{-5ex}
  \begin{flushleft}
    #1
  \end{flushleft}
  \vspace{5ex} 
}
\newif\iffirstauthor% new boolean to detect the first \AddAuthor inside the toc
\newenvironment{l@listauthors}{% environment to be used inside the toc for encapsulating the \AddAuthor commands.
  \quad
  \firstauthortrue
  \renewcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{% local redefinition of \AddAuthor inside l@listauthors environment (used inside the toc)
    \iffirstauthor\firstauthorfalse\else, \fi% if it is the first author set boolean to false otherwise add a comma
    ##1% output author name
  }%
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{The Awesome Chapter}
\ListAuthor{%
  \AddAuthor{First Author}{Goodest Boy}%
  \AddAuthor{Second Author}{Not the Best One}%
}

\chapter{The Awesome Chapter, part 2}
\ListAuthor{%
    \AddAuthor{First Author}{Another Good Boy}%
    \AddAuthor{Second Author}{The Best of Its Kind}%
    \AddAuthor{Third Author}{The Baddie}%
}

\end{document}
```

and here one with `, and`  for the last one.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\newcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{%
  \textbf{#1} \\
  \textit{#2} \\
}

\newcommand{\ListAuthor}[1]{% <-- to avoid potentially unwanted spaces
  \begingroup
    \def\AddAuthor{\string\AddAuthor}% same as above
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begin{l@listauthors}#1\end{l@listauthors}% same as above
    }%
  \endgroup
  \vspace{-5ex}
  \begin{flushleft}
    #1
  \end{flushleft}
  \vspace{5ex} 
}
\newcounter{authorcnt}% used for the number of authors
\newcounter{lastauthor}% number of last author in the end code of l@listauthors
\newcommand*{\authorlist}{}% used for the local author list of a l@listauthors environment
\newenvironment{l@listauthors}{%
  \quad
  \setcounter{authorcnt}{0}% init the number to none
  \def\authorlist{}% empty the local list (should not be needed)
  \renewcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{authorcnt}% we have one more author
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\authorlist\expandafter{% define the author list
      \authorlist% by the current list
      \stepcounter{authorcnt}% and if the current number
      \ifnum\value{authorcnt}>1 , % is > 1 by a comma
        \ifnum \value{authorcnt}=\value{lastauthor} and \fi% and if the current number is the last by "and" + space
      \fi
      ##1% and always by the author name
    }%
  }
}{%
  \setcounter{lastauthor}{\value{authorcnt}}%
  \setcounter{authorcnt}{0}% start the output again with author number 0
  \authorlist
  \par
}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{The Awesome Chapter}
\ListAuthor{%
  \AddAuthor{First Author}{Goodest Boy}%
  \AddAuthor{Second Author}{Not the Best One}%
}

\chapter{The Awesome Chapter, part 2}
\ListAuthor{%
    \AddAuthor{First Author}{Another Good Boy}%
    \AddAuthor{Second Author}{The Best of Its Kind}%
    \AddAuthor{Third Author}{The Baddie}%
}

\end{document}
```

And last but not least a solution, where for two authors only `and` without comma is used:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\newcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{%
  \textbf{#1} \\
  \textit{#2} \\
}

\newcommand{\ListAuthor}[1]{% <-- to avoid potentially unwanted spaces
  \begingroup
    \def\AddAuthor{\string\AddAuthor}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begin{l@listauthors}#1\end{l@listauthors}}
  \endgroup
  \vspace{-5ex}
  \begin{flushleft}
    #1
  \end{flushleft}
  \vspace{5ex} 
}
% This is almost the same as above, only the conditionals are changed
\newcounter{authorcnt}
\newcounter{lastauthor}
\newcommand*{\authorlist}{}
\newenvironment{l@listauthors}{%
  \quad
  \setcounter{authorcnt}{0}%
  \def\authorlist{}%
  \renewcommand{\AddAuthor}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{authorcnt}%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\authorlist\expandafter{%
      \authorlist
      \stepcounter{authorcnt}%  
      \ifnum\value{authorcnt}>1 % for more than one authors add a separator
        \ifnum \value{authorcnt}=\value{lastauthor}% before the last author
          \ifnum \value{authorcnt}>2
            , and % and this, if they are more than 2
          \else
            \ and % and this, if less than two
          \fi
        \else , \fi% before all other authors only a comma
      \fi
      ##1%
    }%
  }
}{%
  \setcounter{lastauthor}{\value{authorcnt}}%
  \setcounter{authorcnt}{0}%
  \authorlist
  \par
}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{The Awesome Chapter}
\ListAuthor{%
  \AddAuthor{First Author}{Goodest Boy}%
  \AddAuthor{Second Author}{Not the Best One}%
}

\chapter{The Awesome Chapter, part 2}
\ListAuthor{%
    \AddAuthor{First Author}{Another Good Boy}%
    \AddAuthor{Second Author}{The Best of Its Kind}%
    \AddAuthor{Third Author}{The Baddie}%
}

\end{document}
```

I would prefer this one:

[image]

It should be easy to extend this last solutions with additional conditionals (or to remove some), if you want other result.

Comment: Sorry, poor wording on my part. Your preferred version was the desired one. Thank you so much.

Care to explain how the code works?

Comment: @Andre See the newly added comments inside the code examples.

Comment: One more question. I'm not yet familiar with `@` being used as a part of environment name. Is `@` there due to deliberate usage?

Comment: @Andre It's not really possible to define *internal* environments. Nevertheless, I've used a `@` to indicate an internally used environment. Using `l@` was analogue to the `\l@…`-commands like `\l@section` etc. for toc entries.

Comment: That's interesting, but, without any disrespect, to my understanding that was quite hacky.

Sometimes I wonder if there really are "proper" TeX practices (and as such, my practices are often "improper" due to failure of understanding), or TeX is really "hacky" stuff.

Of course, I'm speaking this as a mere hobbyist and I need (and really want) to deepen my understanding.

Comment: @Andre With LaTeX3 the distinction between internal functions, variables etc. and user interface is much sharper. However, since TeX itself does not know something like *modules* and associated *scopes*, such distinctions are ultimately with LaTeX always only conventions but no technically enforced mechanisms. And please note, the name of environments and macros in my example are completely subjective decisions and do not matter for the solution itself. So if you have questions about usage of `@` or when or how to define internal macros or environments, please ask them as new questions.